# Sound card not recognized after update

Tags: sound

I've found that after an update, elementary OS no longer shows my intel sound card on system settings and I have no sound. I can only see the HDMI output, which is selected now as the only output. I've reinstalled and reloaded alsa without luck. Also, I've just seen that the audio icon that used to be on wingpanel it's not there.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

The output for the alsa script can be seen [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=b654d97225b78653716e70f2715d8718f571a554).

Comment: Misteriously, after being tweaking my EFI partition to recover rEFInd (I think Windows had wiped it), audio is again functional (I don't really see the relation between both things, I guess they don't relate), but the volume icon is still missing.